# Need to get Asyn task return value in string in android

Tags: android, json, android-asynctask

I need to get the AsyncTask result in my string variable, look it out my coding

**My Async class**

```
   String result =  new GetFavCityList().execute();

    // getFavcity List
        public class GetFavCityList extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                FavCity.clear();
                getfavcity();
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                super.onPostExecute(result);

            }

        }
```

**My parsing function**

```
    public void getfavcity() {

            FavCity.clear();

            String url = Utility.gBasepath + "getCityList/" + gCountryValue + "/"
                    + gFavState.replaceAll(" ", "%20");

            JSONObject json = Getjsonurl.getJsonUrl(url, Profile.this);
    }
```

Now, I need to get the json returned value in my string result, how to get the values Please help me to get the values.

Thanks.

Comment: change `null` in `return null` in `doInBackground` method to any string that you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First change return type of  `getfavcity()` from **void** to **String** .

Like,

```
public String getfavcity() {
     FavCity.clear();
     String url = Utility.gBasepath + "getCityList/" + gCountryValue + "/"
                    + gFavState.replaceAll(" ", "%20");

     JSONObject json = Getjsonurl.getJsonUrl(url, Profile.this);
     return json.toString();
    }
```

Second in `doInBackground()`

```
@Override
 protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   FavCity.clear();                   
   return getfavcity();
  }
```

And last and main..

use `.get()` method of AsyncTask **(Note: its a UI Blocking function)**

```
String result =  new GetFavCityList().execute().get();
```

**Best approach:**

Instead of using `.get()` method of AsyncTask just use your String result in `onPostExecute()` of AsyncTask.

Answer (score 0):

Make `getfavcity()` return your string and then return that string in `doInBackground()`

Answer (score -1):

```
new GetFavCityList().get();
```

Try with above method. But you need to change the parameter Void to String

Comment: get() is blocking the app will freeze